# Complex request with Criteria API

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

I am implementing some kind of school logic. I have Student entity witch has  the List of Exams that he passed:

```
 @Entity
 @Getter
 @Setter
 public class Student {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
     @Column(name = "student_id")
     private Long id;

     @Column("name")
     private String name;

     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
     private List<Exam> exams;
 }
```

The Exam itself has mark value and prePost identifier (The exam can be before attending classes or after that)

```
 @Entity
 @Getter
 @Setter
 public class Exam {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
     @Column(name = "exam_id")
     private Long id;

     @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
     @JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
     private Student student;

     @Column("prePost")
     private String prePost;

     @Column("mark")
     private int mark;
 }
```

One of the points that should be implemented is search Students by name and Exams that they have passed.Well there are three filters on frontend: Student name and Exam mark. Well I'm using Criteria API for this logic. The main idea here is to create set of Specifications and then call for StudentRepository method:

```
 List<Student> findAll(Specification<Student> spec);
```

where spec is the result of conjunction of all created Specification objects.

Well, I have difficulties with implementing search by Exams. Let me explain the correct logic with the help of if-else statement in a meta-language manear.

```
 if(student has at least one Post Exam) {
     for(Exam exam : student.exams) {
         if(exam.mark == selectedMark && exam.prePost == POST){
              *Current student is suitable*
         }
     }
 } else {
     for(Exam exam : student.exams) {
         if(exam.mark == selectedMark && exam.prePost == PRE){
              *Current student is suitable*
         }
     }
 }
```

Here is the code with the help of witch I tried to implement this logic

```
   private Specification<Student> participantByExam(final Integer mark) {
    return Objects.nonNull(mark) ? (root, query, cb) -> {

        final Subquery<Exam> subquery = query.subquery(Exam.class);
        final Root<Exam> examRoot = subquery.from(Exam.class);

        final Expression<Object> expression = cb.selectCase()
                .when(cb.equal(root.join(Student_.exams).get(Exam.prePost), POST), cb.literal(POST))
                .otherwise(cb.literal(PRE));

        final Predicate predicate = cb.and(
                cb.equal(examRoot.get(Exam_.student), root),
                cb.equal(examRoot.get(Exam_.mark), mark),
                cb.equal(examRoot.get(Exam_.prePost), expression)
        );

        query.distinct(true);
        subquery
                .select(root.join(Student_.exams))
                .where(predicate);

        return cb.exists(subquery);

    } : null;
}
```

The problem I get here is incorrect using of conjunction: There is conjunction with Students who has Post tests and Students who has certain mark for one of their results. But I want to receive Students who has Post Exams with certain mark.

Could you please somehow help me such a complex request logic? Or maybe write correct SQL request for this one.

Comment: This is not a site to get your homework done :(

Comment: @PaulWasilewski, I've posted my attempt to create this logic, hope  it'll be helpful for you